# how to Check string present in database column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have document table with fields `id`, `sender_id`, `receiver_id` and `receiver_id` contains string value like **U12,U13,U14** now I currently logged in user and I want to find all records in which `receiver_id` contains my `user_id` means my `user_id` is `U13`. now how to write the query to fetch records.

my query is:

```
$selDoc="SELECT * FROM documents WHERE sender_id='U".$_SESSION['userId']."' OR  "U".$_SESSION['userId']." IN (receiver_id) ORDER BY id DESC";
```

but I got the error Unknown column 'U13' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You string concatenation is messed up, it should be: (*further simplified*)

```
$selDoc="SELECT * FROM documents WHERE 'U".$_SESSION['userId']."' IN (senderID,receiver_id) ORDER BY id DESC";
```

when the statement above is parsed, it will then look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   documents 
WHERE  'UXX' IN (senderID,receiver_id)  // where XX is the userID
ORDER  BY id DESC
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JW the right syntax for `IN` is `WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)`

Comment: once timer stopped  i  will accept your answer

Comment: @YogeshSuthar No, `column_name IN (value1,value2,...)` is very different from `value1 IN (col1, col2, col3,...)`

Comment: @JW its not working for comparing in string

Comment: `find_in_set('U".$_SESSION['userId']."',receiver_id)` will work correctly

Comment: means it works fine if receiver_id contains only one value but in case of string it not works for that find_in_set() works

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote there. Furthermore you should consider using bind variables in your query (assigning the values to look for to variables and then using placeholders in your query) to avoid problems of SQL injection (If you dont know what that is, look it up, it is vitally important to know!)