# Mysql syntax error most popular

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am trying to retrieve the top 5 values in a certain column in a mysql database.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `dep_aerodrome`,
       Count(`dep_aerodrome`) AS `cnt`
FROM   sectors
WHERE ( `group` = '".$_SESSION['GROUP']."'
        AND ( $bases ) NOT IN dep_aerodrome )
GROUP  BY `dep_aerodrome`
ORDER  BY `cnt` DESC
LIMIT  5
```

The query contains a `WHERE` clause and `NOT IN` to not include airports that are registered as bases.

I am getting the following syntax error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dep_aerodrome) GROUP BY `dep_aerodrome` ORDER BY `cnt` DESC LIMIT 5' at line 1

and I cannot figure out where it is coming from. Can anyone help out?

Comment: MySQL does not care about your PHP script, but only about the query it is _actually receiving_ – so please be a little bit smarter and show us the latter one as well, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `dep_aerodrome`,
       Count(`dep_aerodrome`) AS `cnt`
FROM   sectors
WHERE `group` = '".$_SESSION['GROUP']."'
        AND ( $bases ) 
        AND dep_aerodrome NOT IN ($some_values)
GROUP  BY `dep_aerodrome`
ORDER  BY `cnt` DESC
LIMIT  5
```

I think you want to do this like this. `$some_values` can be in the format of `'value1','value2',...` as in:

```
dep_aerodrome NOT IN ('value1','value2',...)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the format wrong for the NOT IN $bases, was missing single quotes around the csv's.

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax for using `NOT IN` is

```
WHERE column_name NOT IN ('value1','value2',...)
```

And If you want to match 1 value with multiple columns check this.

[Different approach of using IN clause in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117492/different-approach-of-using-in-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you, I had the format wrong for the NOT IN $bases, was missing single quotes around the csv's.