# Simplify php code - connect to a database

Tags: php, mysql

Here I have a php code that connects to a database, selects a row by id and creates an associative array from this row using a `while` loop. Do I have to write this code over and over again to create arrays from other rows by id? Maybe there is a chance to simplify this php code somehow? Please look at my code. BTW I am new in php...

```
<?php    
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = '_erica';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = 1;";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = 2;";
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = 3;";
$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = 4;";
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = 5;";
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = 6;";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
$result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
$result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
$result6 = $conn->query($sql6);

while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $bcgrnd = $row1["link"];
}

while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $recipes = $row2["link"];
}

while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $header = $row3["link"];
}

while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {
    $menu = $row4["link"];
}
while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) {
    $beauty = $row5["link"];
}

while($row6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()) {
    $kids = $row6["link"];
}

?>
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5,6);

Comment: And than `$bcgrnd[$row1["id"]][] = $row1["link"];`

Comment: @Kirill Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

And then you can loop over all results like this:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $link = $row["link"];
    $data[$id]["link"] = $link;

    // add more fields if you want
}
```

To access for example the link of ID 1, just do:

```
$data[1]["link"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write one or two simple functions for this. Moreover, please note that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Here is an example how you can achieve this with some simple functions:

```
<?php
    function DB() {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';
        $db = '_erica';
        return new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
    }

    function query($id) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `pics` WHERE `id` = $id";
        return DB()->query($query);
    }

    $result = query(1); // will fetch records for ID 1
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $bcgrnd = $row["link"];
    }

    $result = query(2); // will fetch records for ID 2
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $bcgrnd = $row["link"];
    }
?>
```

By adapting this approach, you can fetch data for a specific ID. If you don't like this solution, consider using [MySQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117492/different-approach-of-using-in-clause-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [in()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)  function finds a match in the given arguments, you can use it

```
select pics where id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <?php    
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $db = '_erica';
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $bcgrnd[$row["id"]][] = $row["link"];
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a Query and Limit it to 6 results, it takes up less resources just pulling 6 results:

```
SELECT * FROM `pics` ORDER BY `[PRIMARY KEY]` LIMIT 6
```