# PHP, MYSQL array from form checkboxes into variables

Tags: php, sql, arrays, checkbox

Im creating a form which has multiple checkboxes based on a sql query so the results values are usually always different

```
<input type="checkbox" name="warrior[]" value="<? echo $warrior_id; ?>">
```

but i dont know how to take the values of the boxes that the user has checked from the array. Each checkbox has the id of a row in my database.

I need to run each id that is checked in another query to bring up more details i need for the rest of the script.

> "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE id='$????'"

There is up to 10 values in the array (up to 10 checkboxes)

Thank you for any advise

Comment: use IN clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117492/different-approach-of-using-in-clause-in-mysql

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_POST['warrior']`` ? See what the POST contains first

Comment: it might help you: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: This kind of form submission is very unpopular these days. Use AJAX. Just advice `$_POST['warrior']` is the array that you would loop over.

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="warrior[]" value="<? echo $warrior_id; ?>">
```

**In PHP - you can implode checked value array. and check with [IN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) in your database**

```
$getvalues = $_GET['warrior']; //only for example i am using this. you have to filter and do validation on it.
$getImplodeValue = implode(',', $getvalues);

$sqlQuery = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE id IN '$getImplodeValue'";
```

Comment: Note that this code is **not** secure. An attacker could perform an SQL injection. You should use PDO or Prepared Statements and validate each single ID before putting them in your statement.

Comment: please read comment i already told him that i  only want to explain that how he can use implode and in .

Comment: thanks, so when i have the query, do i cycle through the results with while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery)) {

Comment: and also dont forget to upvote and accept answer if its helpful for you ;) .

Answer (score 0):

1. check your validation

2.Then use below:

```
$getWarrior = $_REQUEST['warrior'];  //get value 

$arrWarrior = '';

if(!empty($getWarrior))
{          
  $arrWarrior = implode(',', $getWarrior);
}

$sqlQuery = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE 1";
if(!empty($arrWarrior))
{
   $sqlQuery .= " and id IN ($getImplodeValue)";
}
```